# How to change time of a recurring Event time in fullcalendar 5

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullcalendar 5 and have some recurring weekly Events on a weekly calendar.  The Events are initialized by the backend.  I can change the times of those events via drag, resize, or with code, but when I go forward or back a week with the Prev/Next buttons, they revert to their prior time.

Is there a way to change a recurring event such that whatever is handling the repeat logic knows about it so that the new time is retained?

For changing with code, setStart() and setEnd() change the event on the page.  But then prev/next does not retain the change.  I start assign startTime and endTime values but that didn't help.

I got it to work by remove the event and adding a new one.  Don't know if there's a more elegant solution.

```js
let weekDay = '' + myEvent.start.getDay();
let startTime = myEvent.start.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
let endTime =  myEvent.end.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
let newEvent = { "start" : new Date(myEvent.start), 
  "end" : new Date(myEvent.end), 
  "startTime" : startTime, 
  "endTime" : endTime, 
  "daysOfWeek" : weekDay,
  "title" : "XYZZY", 
   "id" : "111",    
}; 
myEvent.remove();
this.addEvent(newEvent);
```

Comment: To be clear, do you want to amend the whole sequence of recurring events, so they all start/end at a different point, or are you wanting to take a specific instance of the recurring event and just amend that single instance? (e.g. if you're an Outlook or Google Calendar user, you may be familiar with the UX in those tools which asks if you want to amend all occurrences of the event, or just the current one - you need to clarify what you're proposing in your question, before anyone can even begin to suggest anything useful).

Comment: Yes, I want all instances of the Event to change.  I did get it work by remove the event and adding a new one.  Not sure if there is not a more elegant solution....
[code]

Comment: you changed the time of your event but it has to be reflected into your events source

Comment: I don't know how you got the events into the calendar to begin with, but if you're using a feed from a dyanmic source (e.g. JSON URL, or a callback function) you'll need to update the event details at the source so that when the feed is refreshed from the server (which normally happens when you change the date range in the calendar) it still gets the latest version.